# How to get my build directory for appcenter appium test in Azure deveops Pipeline

Tags: android, azure-devops, automated-tests, visual-studio-app-center

i created a YAML file, for azure DevOps pipeline, Apium build directory is a required argument, I set it as appiumBuildDir ='target/upload' i keep getting the message that the directory doesn't exist. How do I get my build directory to use on Devops azure? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to specify `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` in `appiumBuildDir` argument.

> System.DefaultWorkingDirectory :   The local path on the agent where
>   your source code files are downloaded. For example: c:\agent_work\1\s

For details about predefined variable , please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agent-variables).